# Lucene's Highlighter.getBestFragments method return empty string when a query contains forward slash

Tags: java, lucene, special-characters, lucene-highlighter

I have an application in which Highlighter.getBestFragments return correctly when a query like "fulltext:rajath AND filepath:rajath" is entered. However if the same query contain a "/" in the filepath is entered, meaning if the query is like "fulltext:rajath AND filepath:rajath/rajath1", Highlighter.getBestFragments method returns an empty string. Please let me know how this problem could be solved. I am suspecting heavily that the issue is because of the forward slash in the query. Is there any way to escape it?

Currently I am using lucene 2.9.3 in my application where the highlighting is not happening correctly. But the query "fulltext:rajath AND filepath:rajath/rajath1" used to highlight keyword rajath correctly in lucene 2.2.0. Both in 2.2.0 and 2.9.3 When "fulltext:rajath AND filepath:rajath/rajath1" is entered, internal query changes to [+fulltext:rajath +filepath:"rajath rajath1"]

Answer (score 0):

in Lucene 4.x forward slash (`/`) is now a special character, which is used to signal a regular expression search.  You will need to [escape your slashes](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters), like:

```
String query = "filepath:rajath\\/rajath1";
```

Or you can have [lucene do the escaping](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#escape%28java.lang.String%29) for you, like:

```
String searchfor = "rajath/rajath1";
String escapedsearch = QueryParserBase.escape(searchfor);
String query = "filepath:" + escapedsearch;
```

Comment: Currently I am using lucene 2.9.3 in my application where the highlighting is not happening correctly. But the query "fulltext:rajath AND filepath:rajath/rajath1" used to highlight keyword rajath correctly in lucene 2.2.0. Both in 2.2.0 and 2.9.3 When "fulltext:rajath AND filepath:rajath/rajath1" is entered, internal query changes to [+fulltext:rajath +filepath:"rajath rajath1"].